# Can a API backed by a RDMS be refactored into Micro services?

Tags: api, microservices

*Working on an API...*

Consider an example database like the following for some enterprise-facing application:

```
+-------------------------------+
|            tables             |
+-------------------------------+
| account_achievement_mappings  |
| account_company_mappings      |
| account_document_mappings     |
| account_feature_mappings      |
| account_group_mappings        |
| account_notification_mappings |
| accounts                      |
| achievements                  |
| companies                     |
| company_document_mappings     |
| company_feature_mappings      |
| documents                     |
| features                      |
| group_company_mappings        |
| group_document_mappings       |
| group_feature_mappings        |
| groups                        |
| notifications                 |
+-------------------------------+
```

None of the tables are too complicated, and they are relationships can be pretty well inferred from their names.

---

As I understand, with a micro service architecture, each micro service should have its own database.

I am wondering if it is possible to break up such a schema into sub-schemas, so that it can then refactored from a monolith to a collection of micro services.

For example, since `notifications` are only linked to `accounts` I though that pulling that out and creating a notification engine might be a good first candidate.

---

Edit:

1) If micro services share a database, wouldn't the database become a bottleneck?

2) If I can separate my database into a set of smaller databases, how do I handle the relationships? Maybe this means that I shouldn't be breaking them apart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As I understand, with a micro service architecture, each micro service should have its own database.

I don't consider that a given.  If you need two different APIs that both require access to the same database, I would think that two microservices would still be a natural fit.

> I am wondering if it is possible to break up such a schema into sub-schemas, so that it can then refactored from a monolith to a collection of micro services.

Do you mean database sub-schemas?  I don't think you need that, unless you believe that it would be advantageous for reasons other than your microservices architecture.

> If micro services share a database, wouldn't the database become a bottleneck?

Unlikely, unless you have an enormous amount of traffic. Modern relational databases are designed to handle this kind of multi-user activity with aplomb.

> If I can separate my database into a set of smaller databases, how do I handle the relationships?

Exactly the reason you shouldn't separate it into multiple databases.

There's nothing mystical about microservices.  Microservices are just a response to the complexity of monolithic systems.  As Einstein once said, "As simple as possible, but no simpler."